# forkJoin not working with dynamic array of URLs and POST objects in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

Here is my tech stack

Angular - 6.1.2

TypeScript - 2.7.2

rxjs - 6.2.2

Here is the code for my forkJoin method in Angular. Post requests are being called at the backend. But the params are not being passed.

```
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

        reqArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {

            if(array[i]==true)
            {
                let obj = { name: 'Test', status: array[i] };

                this.reqArray.push(this.http.post(url, { params: obj }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res)));

            }

      }




forkJoin(this.reqArray).subscribe(
       data => {


            console.log(data);

       },
       err => console.error(err)
    );
```

Tried this approach as well, but I get same response.

```
    Observable.forkJoin(this.reqArray).subscribe(
       data => {

             console.log(data);

       },
       err => console.error(err)
    );
```

When I pass data without the for loop in a static way, it works fine.

```
    forkJoin(
        this.http.get(url, { params: obj }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url, { params: obj2 }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url, { params: obj3 }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res)),
        this.http.get(url, { params: obj4 }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res))

    ).subscribe(
        data => {

            console.log(data);

        });
```

But, in my case I would have to create URLs array based on a few conditions, so adding it statically won't be possible.

What should I change in my code?

Comment: `forkJoin` support an array of Observables too so the problem will be somewhere else: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L31

Answer (score 3):

You need to spread the array

```
forkJoin(...this.reqArray)
```

Comment: I had a very similar scenario but spread resulted in a lint issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52486786/2050306

Answer (score 0):

```
const reqArray= {};     
for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i]==true)
            {
                let obj = { name: 'Test', status: array[i] };
                reqArray[i]=this.http.post(url, { params: obj }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res));

            }
      }

forkJoin(reqArray).subscribe(
       data => {
            console.log(data);
       },
       err => console.error(err)
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).