# RXJS - Subscribe to 2 Observables simultaneously and get both values

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have 2 Observables *number$* and *text$*.
I want to subscribe **to both simultaneously** and get their values in an inner subscription.

My code now looks like this:

```
number$.subscribe((nr: number) => {
    text$.subscribe((txt: string) => {
        this.foo(nr, txt);
    });
});
```

Is there any way to combine these two so i only need one subscription?
I know about forkJoin (which probably would work perfectly fine here), but it's deprecated and we don't want to use deprecated functions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is forkJoin, combineLatest, zip and withLatestFrom that all behave a bit differently

Comment: forkJoin would work here, but is deprecrated

Comment: @AndreasRainer no it is not https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: `forkJoin` is not deprecated. The `subscribe` function have changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486786/forkjoin-is-deprecated-resultselector-is-deprecated-pipe-to-map-instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) or [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin), the different is combineLatest emit on every data fired on both Observable, and forkJoin emit when both Observable completed. In most case, you should use `combineLatest`.

For example, when using `combineLatest`, source `number$` fired an value but source `text$` didn't fire, then the pipeline wait for `text$` to fire an value and then emit both of them to the subsriber, then keep emit the latest value from both source whenever they fire a new value. And remember to unsubscribe them on destroy.

```
combineLatest(number$,text$).subscribe(([numberValue,textValue]) => {
 // Do your logic
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire the events in parallel you should use [fork join](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

If you want to call the events one after the other you can use either [merge map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) or
[switch map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

Comment: I want to fire it in parallel because i need both to call foo()...
forkJoin would work, but is deprecated

Comment: Is not deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486786/forkjoin-is-deprecated-resultselector-is-deprecated-pipe-to-map-instead